# Get a Complete Score from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-form-quiz

I have a spreadsheet collecting from multiple quizzes.  Each varies in length and points available. I am using onFormSubmit trigger in my spreadsheet to copy relevant info (name, email, score) of the most recent submission over to another sheet for the next step of the workflow.

```
var score = inSheet.getRange(inRow, colNoScore).getValue();
```

This returns the value of "5", and not "5/10" as it is displayed in the spreadsheet.

How do I access not only the value of correct responses, but also the possible total so that I can create an average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getValue()` use `getDisplayValue()`

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue